# attach EBS volume to EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I create a Linux Amazon Instance with default 8G EBS volume. After that, I create a new 20G EBS volume and mount it to `/mnt/my-data`.

When I run `$ df -h`. It's show:

```
/dev/xvda1 7.9G Mounted on /
/dev/xvdf  20G  Mounted on /mnt/my-data
```

I am very new with Linux, so I just want to know:

1. The folder `/mnt/my-data` can hold the file with maximize volume is `20G or 28G` ?
2. The folder `/var`  can hold the file with maximize volume is 8G or 28G ?
3. Now I want to mount `/dev/xvdf` to `/var`, what should I do?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The folder /mnt/my-data can hold the file with maximize volume is 20G or 28G ?

20GB. what you see is what you get. (in fact a little less than 20GB as some space will be eaten up by filesystem metadata

> The folder /var can hold the file with maximize volume is 8G or 28G ?

8GB. again same reasoning as above

> Now I want to mount /dev/xvdf to /var, what should I do?

`umount` from /mnt/my-data and the mount it on /var. By doing this , you will lose all the stuff you have in /var.

```
cd /
umount /mnt/my-data
mount /dev/xvdf /var
```

Comment: so folder /mnt will be 8G max. It is so complicated, while mnt/my-data is 20G max?

Comment: yes, because you have mounted your volume on `/mnt/my-data` and not on `/mnt`.